# PHP; PDO; MySQL INSERT query with drop down

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am struggling with this two input INSERT query. It will not insert anything to the db. First, it is supposed to accept user input and the dropdown menu selection which is the id from another table hence the SELECT query. Once this code is fixed I will set up a relationship between the two tables involved via the 'pubid'.

```
<?php

   error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

   require_once("dbconn.php");

   try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbo);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      exit;
   }

   if(isset($_POST['addBtn'])){
      $q = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO series (title, pubid) VALUES (:title, :pubid)");
      $q->bindParam(':title',$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $q->bindParam(':pubid',$pubid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $q->execute();
   }

   $sql = 'SELECT pubid, name FROM publisher ORDER BY name';
   $q = $conn->query($sql);
   $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>
         Comics DB > Add Series
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comicsdb.css">
   </head>
 <body>
    <div class="main">
       <menu>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="add.php">Add</a></li>
             <li><a href="edit.php">Edit</a></li>
             <li><a href="delete.php">Delete</a></li>
             <li><a href="list.php">List</a></li>
             <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
          </ul>
      </menu>
    <div class="pub_menu">
       <form action="addseries.php" method="POST">
          <p>
            Series: 
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="40" /><br />
            <select>
                <option>Select</option>
                <?php while ($row = $q->fetch()){ ?>
                <option name="pubid" id="pubid" value="<?php echo $row['pubid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Series" name="addBtn" />
         </p>
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

dbconn.php

```
<?php

$dbhost         = '127.0.0.1';
$dbname     = 'comicsdb';
$dbuser         = 'root';
$dbpass     = 'FuckYou';
$dbport         = '3306';
$charset    =   'utf8';
$dbo            = array(
// important! use actual prepared statements (default: emulate prepared statements)
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
// throw exceptions in case of errors (default: stay silent)
, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
// fetch associative arrays (default: mixed arrays)
, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
```

[Edit]

```
<?php

   error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

   require_once("dbconn.php");

   try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbo);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      exit;
   }

   if(isset($_POST['addBtn'])){
      $title = $_POST['title'];
      $pubid = $_POST['pubid'];
      $q = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO series (title, pubid) VALUES (:title, :pubid)");
      $q->bindParam(':title',$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $q->bindParam(':pubid',$pubid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $q->execute();
  }

  $sql = 'SELECT pubid, name FROM publisher ORDER BY name';
  $q = $conn->query($sql);
  $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>
         Comics DB > Add Series
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comicsdb.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="main">
         <menu>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="add.php">Add</a></li>
               <li><a href="edit.php">Edit</a></li>
               <li><a href="delete.php">Delete</a></li>
               <li><a href="list.php">List</a></li>
               <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
         </menu>
         <div class="pub_menu">
            <form action="addseries.php" method="POST">
               <p>
                  Series: 
                  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="40" /><br />
                  <select>
                     <option name="pubid" id="pubid">Select</option>
                     <?php while ($row = $q->fetch()){ ?>
                     <option  value="<?php echo $row['pubid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
                     <?php } ?>
                  </select>
                  <input type="submit" value="Add Series" name="addBtn" />
              </p>
           </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are preparing your query but never actually executing it.

Comment: You're not executing anything. Here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @HoboSapiens I'm in a timezone where it's 1 second later than where you are ;-)

Comment: Ok I just added an 'execute()' to it and it still did not do anything

Comment: The SELECT statement? that works, the INSERT does not.

Comment: It's because you didn't define both `$title` and `$pubid`, you're only putting them in your bind, but not being taken from anywhere. Assign them from your POST array.

Comment: Ok, well as I am a noob, how exactly would I go about that? I have another page that uses an INSERT query that only takes one parameter. I have tried the exact same method but it did not work.

Comment: I've posted an answer below to better demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't assign anything to your variables.

Assign them to your POST arrays:

```
if(isset($_POST['title'],$_POST['pubid'])){

$title = $_POST['title'];
$pubid = $_POST['pubid'];

      $q = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO publisher (title, pubid) VALUES (:title, :pubid)");
      $q->bindParam(':title',$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $q->bindParam(':pubid',$pubid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $q->execute();
   }
```

---

- Kudos to Ghost for catching this.

`<select>` bears the name attribute, not the `<option>`.

Change your `<select>` to read as `<select name="pubid">` and remove the `name="pubid"` from the `<option>`.

---

**Edit:**

As per your edit, you still have an unnamed attribute for the select:

```
<select>
<option name="pubid" id="pubid">Select</option>
```

that needs to read as:

```
<select name="pubid">
<option>Select</option>
```

that's why you're still getting an undefined index notice.

Plus, you can move your id inside it:

```
<select name="pubid" id="pubid">
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74268/discussion-on-answer-by-fred-ii-php-pdo-mysql-insert-query-with-drop-down).

Comment: @bluefeet Thank you. The chat button never showed up for me when trying to help out the OP at the time. Slight bug?